# logging app name along with other information of an api call in wso2 api manager

Tags: logging, wso2-api-manager

In http access log section of api manager documentation has been explained how to create a custom log for each http request to api gateway. it sounds like there is no way to log app name alongside with other information of a request. Can someone explain to me how can I log app name too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a custom sequence as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="mockapi">

    <header name="backend-key-xyz" scope="transport" expression="get-property('api.ut.application.name')"/>
</sequence>
```

Keys can be found here - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/8de92014fccd078930726a1e9fd39f238de60d54/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway/APIMgtGatewayConstants.java#L38

Comment: in which file should I add this sequence? do I need to make any changes to access-log.properties file?

Comment: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/message-mediation/passing-a-custom-authorization-token-to-the-backend/#passing-a-custom-authorization-token-to-the-backend